# Three.js - Is there any way to use a selection box with the Raycaster?

Tags: javascript, three.js, raycasting

I have a GLTF scene where I've experimented with the [example selection box](https://threejs.org/examples/misc_boxselection) ([code](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/misc_boxselection.html)) to select multiple meshes.

However, the results are inaccurate because it picks based on the centroid of each mesh and also gets meshes that are not visible by the camera (viewing one side of a house model selects all the walls in the direction of the box).

I've also experimented using the [Raycaster](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Raycaster), and it works great for picking with the mouse/pointer.

Is there any way to use a selection box or two Vector3 (starting and ending point of the box) with the Raycaster?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `Raycaster` to create a [`Frustum`](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=fru#api/en/math/Frustum).

1. Create two `Plane` objects to represent your camera's `near` anf `far` planes.
2. Use the `Raycaster` to intersect your selection area's start/end points against the `Plane` objects.
3. Use the intersection points to define the `Frustum`.
4. Use [`Frustum.containsPoint`](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=fru#api/en/math/Frustum.containsPoint) and [`Frustum.intersectsObject`](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=fru#api/en/math/Frustum.intersectsObject) to see if a particular object is within your selection area.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm very new to Three.js. Should I look into something specific to start applying your solution? I read about all the concepts in your response, and I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @rd05 Take them one step at a time and try them. If you get stuck, you can always ask more questions. I highly recommend looking through the [three.js examples](https://threejs.org/examples) to learn how things like `Raycaster` can be configured to use screen coordinates to fire into the 3D scene.